# Replace the right-hand-site part in a regular expression

Tags: regex

```
{REGEX(Replace|0000000000|^.{5}|12345)}
```

result in `1234500000`.     I understand that.
The `^` means replace from the left hand side.

How can I replace from the right hand side. The result must be `0000012345`?
A `$` instead of a `^` doesn’t work.

Comment: Could you specify technology in tags, which regex you run?

Comment: `.{5}$` ought to work...

Comment: I use regex in VisualCron.

Comment: .{5}$ give just the result that I need. Thanks Nick.